# Print lines from one file based on contents from another

Tags: python

I have two files, file1.txt looks like this:

```
aaaa
cccc
ffff
gggg
```

And file2.txt looks like this:

```
aaaa  text1
some_random_text_A
bbbb  text2
some_random_text_B
cccc  text3
some_random_text_C
dddd  text4
some_random_text_D
eeee  text5
some_random_text_E
ffff  text6
some_random_text_F
gggg  text7
some_random_text_G
hhhh  text8
some_random_text_H
```

I have developed some Python code that uses the contents of file1.txt to subset file2.txt, such that if a string from file1 is found in file2, the file2 line containing that string as well as the next line are printed to output. Here is my code:

```
import re

nums=set()

with open("file1.txt") as file1:
    for line in file1:
        nums.add(line.strip())

with open("file2.txt") as file2, open("out.txt", "wt") as 
outfile:
    line = file2.readline()
    while line:
        line = line.strip()
        if any(re.match(f"^{word}\\b", line) for word in nums):
            outfile.write(line + "\n")
            line = file2.readline()
            if line:
                outfile.write(line)
            else: 
                outfile.write("\n")
                break
        line = file2.readline()
```

This code gives me the desired result, but there are two problems:

1) in reality file1.txt and file2.txt contain millions of lines, and this code is very slow at completing the task, even if file1.txt is broken up to create multiple smaller jobs

2) output printed to out.txt is not visible until the job is finished, so it is difficult to monitor progress, and if the job is interrupted prior to finishing then out.txt will be empty

Is there another approach to accomplishing this task that would be much faster/more efficient? Thanks!

Comment: sounds like you need `pandas` and then to simply perform a `join` on your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the first problem, this line is inefficient:

```
if any(re.match(f"^{word}\\b", line) for word in nums)
```

It's doing a check against every entry in `nums` in sequence, even though `nums` is a set.

Instead you could do something like this, which should get there in a single step:

```
if line.split()[0] in nums:
```

---

For monitoring progress, you could call `outfile.flush()` to force the buffer to be written to disk. This would slow performance if you did it too frequently, so you might like to keep a counter and then flush, say, every thousand records:

```
i = 0
...
i += 1
if i % 1000 == 0:
    outfile.flush()
```

Comment: thanks a ton, you wouldn't believe how much faster my script runs with that simple fix!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're basically doing multiple searches, an *iteraviely* more efficient way might be to load the whole file into memory and organize it into a dictionary, although this obviously depends on the file size. That way, you can utilize the O(1) speed of accessing dict keys.

Load all at once:

```py
from pathlib import Path

desired_headers = Path('file1.txt').read_text().splitlines()
file_content = Path('file2.txt').read_text().splitlines()

# Based on your example, "keys" were on the even lines (including 0)
# and "values" were on the odd lines. The slicing here separates them
# out using this assumption.
keys, vals = file_content[::2], file_content[1::2]
mapped_content = {
    # Split on whitespace and strip any remaining.
    # Could also just do "x.split('  ')[0]"
    x.split()[0].strip(): {'full_line': x, 'next_line': y} for x, y in zip(keys, vals)
}
```

Then, you can access the lines directly:

```py
>>> for i in desired_headers:
>>>     print(mapped_content[i])

{'full_line': 'ffff  text6', 'next_line': 'some_random_text_F'}
{'full_line': 'aaaa  text1', 'next_line': 'some_random_text_A'}
{'full_line': 'cccc  text3', 'next_line': 'some_random_text_C'}
{'full_line': 'gggg  text7', 'next_line': 'some_random_text_G'}
```